# Cannot get the right date format in MaterialDatePicker android

Tags: java, android, date, daterangepicker

I tried below code but i can not get the result which I want.

```
    MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
    builder.setTitleText("Select A Date");
    
    final MaterialDatePicker<Pair<Long, Long>> materialDatePicker = builder.build();
    
    date_picker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            materialDatePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER");
        }
    });
    
    materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Pair<Long, Long>>() {
        @Override
        public void onPositiveButtonClick(Pair<Long, Long> selection) { 
        
            Long start = selection.first;
            Calendar start_cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            start_cal.setTimeInMillis(start);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat_start = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
            start_date = simpleDateFormat_start.format(start_cal.getTime());
            
        
            Long end = selection.second;
            Calendar end_cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            end_cal.setTimeInMillis(end);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat_end = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
            end_date = simpleDateFormat_end.format(end_cal.getTime());
            
            String final_text = start_date + "  to  " + end_date;
            date_picker.setText(final_text);
            Log.e("Check65", "Date : " + final_text);
            
        }
    });
```

I want
startdate: 2021-01-01
enddate: 2021-02-02

but i get
startdate: 2021-01-01
enddate: 2021-02-32

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `SimpleDateFormat` you should use `YYYY-MM-dd` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD` as uppercase DD means day of the year and you want the day of the month. [For reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat)